# Long equation problems

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am given this equation:

$$15x^6+31x^5-254x^4-352x^3+329x^2+9x-18=0$$

I know how to solve this question but the problem is it is too long to plug in numbers, what am I advised to do?

Comment: Well you would need to apply intermediate value theorem to reduces the tries you need to use the rational roots theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy thing to check is if it has rational roots. You only need check for factors of the form $ax+b$ where $a$ is a factor of $15$ and $b$ is a factor (positive or negative) of $18$.

You should for example find that $5x-3$ is a factor i.e $\frac {3}{5}$ is a root.

There's also a much simpler factor for you to find.

Divide through by these factors to obtain a quartic $$3x^4+2x^3-50x^2+2x+3
$$ which has no more rational roots.

Comment: Yes I know. There are two linear factors $x+2$ and $5x-3$, do you mean that we have to try by luck? What about the other roots?

Comment: By hand you try systematically. Once you have a factor (and you now have two) you divide through by them thus reducing the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: I've added to the answer for the next stage.

Comment: Ohh i see. That's a reciprocal equation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=15x^6+31x^5-254x^4-352x^3+329x^2+9x-18$$
$$f(x)=(x+2) (5 x-3) \left(x^2-4 x+1\right) \left(3 x^2+14 x+3\right)$$ after factoring the quartic given by @S. Dolan

Comment: @Gord452. Noooo ! This is one of the many areas where I am totally ignorant. Cheers :-(